# How to Filter the value pasted in TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, paste, jquery-events

Have Text Area were we enter semicolon separated values, able to process for the keyboard events and validating successfully.How to validate the same on copy paste.

```
$(function () {
    var kpi = document.getElementById('<%=this.d.ClientID%>').value;
    var tb = $('#<%= TextBox.ClientID %>');
    $(tb).keypress(function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("[0-9;]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str) && !($(this).val().match(/;{2,}/))) {
            var as = $(this).val().match(/;/ig) || [];
            var len = as.length;
            if (len < kpi) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
    $(tb).keyup(function (e) {
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (($(this).val().match(/[;]{2,}/g))) {
            var shortenedString = $(this).val().substr(0, ($(this).val().length - 1));
            $(this).val(shortenedString);
            return true;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
    $(tb).on('paste input propertychange', function (e) {
        //Validate interger with ; on paste and rest not allowed
    })
});
```

Comment: The `on('input')` should trigger events when you paste the text into text area. Are you saying it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the keyup event to post-validate the input. The pasted value in the textarea is not available before this, such as at keypress. You can determine if it's a paste by checking, for example:

```
event.ctrlKey
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyup event, the alternative try to your implementation can be something like this:

```
$(tb).live('keyup', function (e) {
     this.value = this.value.replace(/[;]{2,}/g, "");
       }
 });
```

This will replace semicolon from the entered value on doing paste to the textarea.